# If matrices $A,B$ and $(A^2-B^2)$ are all positive semidefinite, is $A-B$ also?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is in the title. I have not found a counter example, so I try to prove it.
However, contract diagonalization at the same time seems useless.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Sorry，I forgot this .A,B are all real and symmetrical.